Any better algorithm compared to continuous fractions for solving Pell Equation?
Pell equation : x^2 - ny^2 = 1
Solving it with continuous fractions is well known, such as following  code:
def PELL(n):    
    dj = b = m = int(sqrt(n))
    x = c = i = new = 1   
    while new != m * 2:
        c = (n - b * b) // c    
        new = (m + b) // c          # new is continuous fraction
        x,dj = dj, new * dj + x   
        i += 1                      # i is period
        b = new * c - b   
    if i % 2 == 0 : x = 2 * x ^ 2 + 1
    return x,sqrt((x^2 - 1) // n))

for large n, the i (period ) will be large normally (not always), for example, when n = 12345678910111213, no answer return after one day's runnning, and I have no idea how long it will take. Thus I try to find a more fast algorithm. Though a new method is invented by a Chinese guy based on new math's idea, the time complexity is almost same as continuous fractions.
Question 1 : Is there a way to  calculate i in a short time for any n?
Question 2 : Is there any better algorithm for Pell Equation？
